# Why dill dumps external classes by reference, no matter what?

Tags: python, pickle, dill

In the example below, I have placed the class `Foo` inside its own module `foo`.

Why is the external class dumped by ref? The instance `ff` is not being dumped with its source code.

I am using Python 3.4.3 and dill-0.2.4.

```
import dill
import foo

class Foo:
    y = 1
    def bar( self, x ):
        return x + y

f = Foo()
ff = foo.Foo()

print( dill.dumps( f, byref=False, recurse=True ) )
print( '\n' )
print( dill.dumps( ff, byref=False, recurse=True ) )
```

Well, the code above is actually wrong (should be `Foo.y`, instead of `y`). Correcting the code gives me an exception while dumping the `f` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  The `foo.Foo` instance (`ff`) pickles by reference because it's defined in a file.  This is primarily for compactness of the pickled string.  So the primary issue I can think of when importing a class by reference is that the class definition is not found on the other resource you might want to unpickle to (i.e. no module `foo` exists there).  I believe that's a current feature request (and if it's not, feel free to submit a ticket on the github page).

Note, however, if you do modify the class dynamically, it does pull in the dynamically modified code to the pickled string.

```
>>> import dill
>>> import foo
>>> 
>>> class Foo:
...     y = 1
...     def bar( self, x ):
...         return x + Foo.y
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> ff = foo.Foo()
```

So when `Foo` is defined in `__main__`, `byref` is respected.

```
>>> dill.dumps(f, byref=False)              
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x04\x00\x00\x00typeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04X\x03\x00\x00\x00Fooq\x05h\x01X\x06\x00\x00\x00objectq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(X\r\x00\x00\x00__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cX\x03\x00\x00\x00barq\rcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x0e(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x0fC]\xe3\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0b\x00\x00\x00|\x01\x00t\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x17S)\x01N)\x02\xda\x03Foo\xda\x01y)\x02\xda\x04self\xda\x01x\xa9\x00r\x05\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x07<stdin>\xda\x03bar\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x10\x85q\x11Rq\x12c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\rNN}q\x13tq\x14Rq\x15X\x07\x00\x00\x00__doc__q\x16NX\n\x00\x00\x00__module__q\x17X\x08\x00\x00\x00__main__q\x18X\x01\x00\x00\x00yq\x19K\x01utq\x1aRq\x1b)\x81q\x1c.'
>>> dill.dumps(f, byref=True)
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'
>>>
```

However, when the class is defined in a module, `byref` is not respected.

```
>>> dill.dumps(ff, byref=False)
b'\x80\x03cfoo\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'
>>> dill.dumps(ff, byref=True)
b'\x80\x03cfoo\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'
```

Note, that I wouldn't use the `recurse` option in this case, as `Foo.y` will likely infinitely recurse.  That's also something that I believe there's current ticket for, but if there isn't, there should be.

Let's dig a little deeper… what if we modify the instance...

```
>>> ff.zap = lambda x: x + ff.y
>>> _ff = dill.loads(dill.dumps(ff))
>>> _ff.zap(2)
3
>>> dill.dumps(ff, byref=True)
b'\x80\x03cfoo\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00zapq\x03cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x04(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x05CY\xe3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0b\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00t\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x17S)\x01N)\x02\xda\x02ff\xda\x01y)\x01\xda\x01x\xa9\x00r\x04\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x07<stdin>\xda\x08<lambda>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08c__builtin__\n__main__\nX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\tNN}q\ntq\x0bRq\x0csb.'
>>> dill.dumps(ff, byref=False)
b'\x80\x03cfoo\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00zapq\x03cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x04(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x05CY\xe3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0b\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00t\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x17S)\x01N)\x02\xda\x02ff\xda\x01y)\x01\xda\x01x\xa9\x00r\x04\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x07<stdin>\xda\x08<lambda>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08c__builtin__\n__main__\nX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\tNN}q\ntq\x0bRq\x0csb.'
>>>
```

No biggie, it pulls in the dynamically added code.  However, we'd probably like to modify `Foo` and not the instance.

```
>>> Foo.zap = lambda self,x: x + Foo.y
>>> dill.dumps(f, byref=True)
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'
>>> dill.dumps(f, byref=False)
b'\x80\x03cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x04\x00\x00\x00typeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04X\x03\x00\x00\x00Fooq\x05h\x01X\x06\x00\x00\x00objectq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(X\x03\x00\x00\x00barq\x0bcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x0c(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\rC]\xe3\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0b\x00\x00\x00|\x01\x00t\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x17S)\x01N)\x02\xda\x03Foo\xda\x01y)\x02\xda\x04self\xda\x01x\xa9\x00r\x05\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x07<stdin>\xda\x03bar\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x0e\x85q\x0fRq\x10c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bNN}q\x11tq\x12Rq\x13X\x07\x00\x00\x00__doc__q\x14NX\r\x00\x00\x00__slotnames__q\x15]q\x16X\n\x00\x00\x00__module__q\x17X\x08\x00\x00\x00__main__q\x18X\x01\x00\x00\x00yq\x19K\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00zapq\x1ah\x0c(h\rC`\xe3\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0b\x00\x00\x00|\x01\x00t\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x17S)\x01N)\x02\xda\x03Foo\xda\x01y)\x02\xda\x04self\xda\x01x\xa9\x00r\x05\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x07<stdin>\xda\x08<lambda>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x1b\x85q\x1cRq\x1dc__builtin__\n__main__\nX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\x1eNN}q\x1ftq Rq!utq"Rq#)\x81q$.'
```

Ok, that's fine, but what about the `Foo` in our external module?

```
>>> ff = foo.Foo()
>>> 
>>> foo.Foo.zap = lambda self,x: x + foo.Foo.y
>>> dill.dumps(ff, byref=False)
b'\x80\x03cfoo\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'
>>> dill.dumps(ff, byref=True)
b'\x80\x03cfoo\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'
>>>
```

Hmmm… not good.  So the above is probably a pretty compelling use case to change the behavior `dill` exhibits for classes defined in modules -- or at least enable one of the settings to provide better behavior.

In sum, the answer is: we didn't have a use case for it, so now that we do…  this should be a feature request if it is not already.

Comment: @McKerns Thanks for such a complete answer. I'm not a python expert, and I have been experimenting with dill only for a few hours. But as a complete beginner, when using `byref=False` and `recurse=True`, I would expect `ff` to be pickled with everything required for it to work on any remote (even when the remote does not have the required modules). I think I am being too ambitious here. =) But, is there any way to accomplish that with dill, today or any time soon?

Comment: @NCrawl: The real answer is that this all takes effort, and you've identified a useful case that just hasn't come up to date.  The underlying issue is when the `foo` module doesn't exist -- it's always been assumed that it has to exist.  You can see other recent tickets that also request this (https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/123).   With regard to timing: today no, but probably soon.  I don't think there's too much to code, but code to pickle stuff is delicate to work out so it behaves well.